# What are the types of Infinity and NaN?

Tags: ruby, nan, infinity

I can get `Infinity` and `NaN` by

```
n = 9.0 / 0 #=> Infinity
n.class #=> Float

m = 0 / 0.0 #=> NaN
m.class #=> Float
```

but when I want to access `Infinity` or `NaN` directly:

```
Infinity #=> uninitialized constant Infinity (NameError)
NaN #=> uninitialized constant NaN (NameError)
```

What are `Infinity` and `NaN`? Are they objects, keywords, or something else?

Comment: **tl;dr**: The spelling is the difference, you have to write it all caps like `Float::INFINITY` or `Float::NAN`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see printed as `Infinity` and `NaN` are just the string representations for two special instances of the `Float` class, not keywords or literals. They are returned by floating point division by 0 or by referencing the constants `Float::INFINITY` and `Float::NAN`.

```
Float::INFINITY.class
# => Float
Float::INFINITY.to_s
# => "Infinity"

Float::NAN.class
# => Float
Float::NAN.to_s
# => "NaN"
```

Comment: `Float::INFINITY` is used to represent infinity in general, e.g. `loop.size` returns it, too.

Comment: I supposed to ask something else,but I asked something different..I will come back with my question..I think some thing you missed in your answer... :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want inf/nan literal, use follow:

```
>> Float::INFINITY
=> Infinity
>> Float::NAN
=> NaN
```

See [Float constants list](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Float.html#constants-list)